# My React App state is not in sync with my Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am having a hard time getting my React App working properly.
The thing is that I tried to use UseEffect hooks only to run side effects in my app and this has brought me some problems.
In this simple component I have a chat that get data from Firebase and is capable of updating the Db. I have no problem with the Firebase side but on the front end, the first render is not able to get me the messages into state properly.
I feel that it has of course something to do with async behaviors.

I will try to explain you the flow of my component :
The message text is kept in a const in state call "inputText"; when the form is submited a const call "numberOfMessageSent" is incremented; I have a UseEffect Hook that has [numberOfMessageSent] in its depedency; so after the first mount of the component and when "NumberOfMessageSent" increments the callback will fire; this callback fires 2 async functions: one to fetch the current discussion from the db and another to create a discussion object or update an existing one into the Db. I have a condition :
"numberOfMessagesSent !== 0 && asyncWarperCreateDiscussionInDb()" in the UseEffect Hook so a new discussion empty discussion won't be created the first this component mount.

My problem is that no discussion is displayed (nor properly fetched and stored into state) BEFORE I send a first message. After I send this first message everything works properly.

Can someone help me to understand this better ?
Thank you very much
here is my code :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./card-medium-message.style.scss";
import likeEmpty from "./like-empty.png";
import likeFull from "./like-full.png";
import cancel from "./cancel.png";
import send from "./send.png";
import back from "./back.png";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { UsersListContext } from "../../context/usersList-context/users-list-context";
import { UserContext } from "../../context/user-context/user-context";
import {
  createDiscussionInDb,
  goFetchDiscussionInDb,
  goFetchDisscussion,
} from "../../utils/firebase";
const CardMediumMessage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { usersListCTX } = useContext(UsersListContext);
  const { currentUserContext } = useContext(UserContext);
  const currentUserClickedOn = usersListCTX.filter(
    (user) => user.displayName === params.name
  );
  console.log(currentUserContext);
  console.log(currentUserClickedOn[0]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [numberOfMessagesSent, setNumberOfMessagesSent] = useState(0);

  const asyncWarperFetchDiscussionInDb = async () => {
    if (currentUserClickedOn[0]) {
      const discussion = await goFetchDiscussionInDb(
        currentUserContext.displayName,
        currentUserClickedOn[0].displayName
      );
      setMessages(discussion.messages);
    }
  };

  const asyncWarperCreateDiscussionInDb = async () => {
    await createDiscussionInDb(
      currentUserContext.displayName,
      currentUserClickedOn[0].displayName,
      inputText
    );
    resetField();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    numberOfMessagesSent !== 0 && asyncWarperCreateDiscussionInDb();
    asyncWarperFetchDiscussionInDb();
    console.log(
      "this is written after first render of the component or numberOfMessagesSent was updated"
    );
  }, [numberOfMessagesSent]);

  const messageSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputText == "") {
      return;
    }
    setNumberOfMessagesSent(numberOfMessagesSent + 1);
  };
  const textChanged = (e) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };
  const resetField = () => {
    setInputText("");
  };
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  messages && console.log(messages);
  return (
    <div className="card-medium-warp">
      <div className="card-medium-message">
        <div className="section1" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
          <div className="profile-image-outer-circle">
            {currentUserClickedOn[0] ? (
              <img
                src={`https://api.dicebear.com/5.x/micah/svg?seed=${currentUserClickedOn[0].displayName}`}
                alt="avatar"
                className="profile-image"
              />
            ) : undefined}
          </div>
          {currentUserClickedOn[0] ? (
            <h2 className="name">{currentUserClickedOn[0].displayName} </h2>
          ) : undefined}
          <div
            className="back"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${back})` }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div className="section2">
          {messages
            ? messages.map((messageObject, index) => (
                <p
                  key={index}
                  className={
                    messageObject.by === currentUserContext.displayName
                      ? "sender-message"
                      : "receiver-message"
                  }
                >
                  {messageObject.message}
                </p>
              ))
            : undefined}
        </div>
        <form className="section3" onSubmit={messageSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="input"
            placeholder="your message"
            onChange={textChanged}
            value={inputText}
            autoFocus
          />
          <div
            className="send-message"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${send})` }}
          ></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardMediumMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution so I would like to share it :
My mistake was that I was calling functions that were async in themselves but I didn't chain them in an async/await manner.
This is what I am talking about :

```
  const asyncWarperSequence = async () => {
    numberOfMessagesSent !== 0 && (await asyncWarperCreateDiscussionInDb());
    await asyncWarperFetchDiscussionInDb();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect Fired");
    asyncWarperSequence();
  }, [numberOfMessagesSent]);
```